# More Current from GPIO

Tags: current, gpio

I'm working on a project that uses a GPIO port extender, but I need the ability to sink more current on the GPIO pins.

There are 24 GPIO pins.  Each pin can either be input or output.  The pins need to sink 50mA individually and up to 200mA over all.

Is there a small package that can help with this?  Or maybe there's a port extender that already does this that I don't know about?

Comment: I would look at multi pack transistors

Comment: @SomeHardwareGuy How would I handle the inputs?

Comment: Sometimes high current drivers like that are called relay drivers.

Comment: You only need to buffer the outputs that will be handling a higher current or voltage than the I/O expander can handle.  You don't need to do anything to the input signals unless they are a higher voltage than the I/O expander's inputs can accept.

Comment: Sorry knee jerk reaction we must get the opposite question several times a week :)

Comment: @PeterBennett the pins are selectable as inputs and outputs.

Comment: @PeterBennett I was asking how do I handle the input side of a selectable pin.

Comment: An ULN2003 *may* be what you are looking for, but this specific one has high'ish voltage drop due to darlington outputs. In any case carefully check the datasheet if it fits your application (about which you gave us very little information). There are truckloads of similar devices and surely you can find search terms in the datasheet.

Comment: Can you gang several IO's together to increase current sinking capability? Would just need to take care in code to always drive them to the same state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what your looking for

[MAX7313](http://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/interface/controllers-expanders/MAX7313.html)